# Adding two string values that contain integers in Python

Tags: python

Brand new to Python and coding in general. Teaching myself and playing around with various outputs in Python. I was messing around today and tried to compute two what I believe are string values into the defined floating point format.

```
a = "%.2f" %x + str(float(14.00))
```

returns '3.3514.0'

```
a = "%.2f" %x , str(float(14.00))
```

returns ('3.35, '14.0')

I was able to separate these two values but i was not able to get the proper value of 17.75 computed. I would like to take x (which = 3.3456), round to two decimal places ("%.2f" %x) take the floating value of 14.00 (float(14.00) and add these two together then define that computation with a. so a = x to two decimals + float(14.00).
What am I doing wrong?

-Alfa

Comment: you can not add strings to expect numerical addition. Both of them should be `float` or `int` for that. If both of them are `str` then there won't be numerical addition.

Answer (score 2):

try this 
a = float("%.2f" %x) + float(14.00)

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you're just trying to concat these two strings. In Python '+' used on strings means 'add the second string on the end of first one', so that's why you're getting ugly result. I would suggest to count values out of the string, next use string formating, but If you must do it, It can be something like:

```
a = '%.2f' % str(float_value1 + float_value2)`
```

Better solution is to use **.format**, as someone mentioned.

Comment: Thank you all very much. Through your answers and thinking about this value today it occurred to me that the first value is indeed a string and that's why I was having trouble understanding what the problem was. Again, thank you all very much.

Answer (score -1):

is not

```
a = "%.2f" %x + str(float(14.00))
```

but

```
a = ""%.2f" % str(float(14.00))
```

or better ([doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html))

```
'here {} '.format(str(float(14.00)))
```